Computing the connection form $\omega_1^2$ for $ds^2 = dt^2 + f(t)^2d\theta^2$
For $S^1 \times I$ where $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ consider the following metric $$ds^2 = dt^2 + f(t)^2d\theta^2.$$I want to compute $\omega_1^2$, the connection form.
I let $\theta^1 = dt$ and $\theta^2 = f(t)d\theta$. By the compatibility with the metric and the first structure equations we have the system \begin{align*}d\theta^1 + \omega_1^1\wedge \theta^1 + \omega^1_2 \wedge \theta^2 & = 0,\\
d\theta^2 + \omega_1^2 \wedge \theta^1 + \omega_2^2 \wedge \theta^2 & = 0.
\end{align*}Write $\omega_i^j = a_i^j\theta^1 + \overline{a_i^j}\theta^2$. From the previous system we get \begin{align*}
a_1^2 & = -\overline{a_1^1},\\
\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)} & = \overline{a_1^2} + a_2^2.
\end{align*}I can't fully describe $\omega_1^2$ with this information. Is there something more that I am forgetting and can help me conclude?
I thought about using the second structural equation $$\Omega_1^2 = d\omega_1^2 + \omega_1^1 \wedge \omega^1_2 + \omega_2^1 \wedge \omega^2_2,$$knowing that $\Omega_1^2 = K = -f''(t)/f(t)$ but it doesn't seem helpful.
Question: Is it true that $\omega_1^1 = \omega_2^2 = 0$? Why is it? Because then we get $\omega_1^2 = -f'(t)d\theta$ which agrees (up to a minus sign?) with the expression that on wikipedia $$\omega_i^j = \sum_k \Gamma_{ki}^j\theta^k.$$
Thanks!

This is an orthonormal coframe, so the connection matrix is skew-symmetric. You will find this very question discussed on this site, as I know I have written at least one answer before.

@TedShifrin Yes, I know the connection matrix is skew-symmetric, I use it in the computations. But why does $\omega_1^1 = \omega_2^2 = 0$?

What are the diagonal entries of a skew-symmetric matrix?

@TedShifrin I am sorry, I completely forgot linear algebra for a second. Its trace is zero..

More than that. You’re thinking of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$.
